# Add condition to an existing column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have the following columns in my dataset:

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________________
| ... |Start Date| Start Time |  End Date  |  End Time  | Production Start Date | ... |
|_____|__________|____________|____________|____________|_______________________|_____|
| ... | 01022020 |   180000   |  02022020  |   190000   |       01022020        | ... |
|     |          |            |            |            |                       |     |
```

Sometimes the `Start Date` + `Start Time` etc. values are blank but the `Production Start Date` values are always populated.

When the `Start Date` is empty (`NULL`), for example, I want my dataset (or ideally, graph) to read the `Production Start Date`.

How can I achieve this in Power BI?

I know I can make a conditional column, then within that, determine which column to read data from but is there any way to add a condition to the existing `Start Date` column? I couldn't see such an option in the context menu or subsequent ribbon options.

Is my only option to create a custom conditional column instead?

Comment: Yes, you should create a new conditional column (using M) or computed column (using DAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrey Nikolov mentioned in the comments, the only ways you can achieve this is to:

**1** Create a calculated DAX column.

**2** Create a custom column in query mode (M).

**3** Edit the original source table.

doug